# div appearing before | element

Tags: css, css-float

In this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thbuf/110/

The div "test" is appearing before the | element. This is occurring despite that the "test" is added after | . Is there an issue with css ?

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend {
  /*table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color:#333;
  color:#CCC;
  font-family:Myriad Pro, Verdana;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  height: auto;    
}
html>body #container {
  height: auto;
}

#page{
  padding:0 0 100px 0;   
}

#content{
  padding:15px;   
}
#content h1{
  font-size:3em;   
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#CCC;
  color:#333;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>

  <div id='page'>
    <div id='content'>
      <h1>title</h1>
      <p>some content would go here</p>
      <p>Loet consectetur elementum, faucibus in nulla.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='footer'>
    <div style="display: inline">here is your footer</div>
    <div style="display: inline; float:right;">|</div>
    <div style="display: inline; float:right">test</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `float:right` will make the elements go right starting from the first one. Swap the order of your `div`s in HTML. -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/thbuf/113/

Comment: @Abhitalks: Sorry for posting the answer. The page didn't refresh and so I didn't have a chance to see your comment. If you wish to post your comment as an answer then I'll remove mine (or) will add a reference to your comment.

Comment: @Harry: Never mind. Good that you answered :)

Comment: When you use CSS's `float` property, IIRC you are affecting the rendering order of the elements in the DOM.  Basically, they are removed from the normal flow of rendering... floating the element first and everything flows around it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the `float: right` on both the elements. This makes them act as though they are stacked from the right side of the screen and so the first element in the document order becomes the first from the right followed by the second element.

To reverse them, you just need to reverse the order.

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend {
    /*table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#CCC;
    font-family:Myriad Pro, Verdana;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: auto;    
}
html>body #container {
    height: auto;
}

#page{
     padding:0 0 100px 0;   
}

#content{
     padding:15px;   
}
#content h1{
    font-size:3em;   
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='page'>
  <div id='content'>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>some content would go here</p>
    <p>Loet consectetur elementum, faucibus in nulla.</p>
    <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='footer'>
  <div style="display: inline">here is your footer</div>
  <div style="display: inline; float:right">test</div>
  <div style="display: inline; float:right">test</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I was actually trying to find the reference in the specs for this. From (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position) I think the rule #7 applies here. What say?

Comment: @Abhitalks: Yeah 7 and 9 apply. The first element in doc order is placed as far right as possible meaning that the next one can only be placed by its left edge (because it can't go any farther to the right).

Answer (score 0):

Just add new div to contain the sub divs like so:

```
<div style="float:right">
```

Hind the working fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/thbuf/114/)